# safari crashes with this simple css?

Tags: html, css, safari

```
<style>
    .panel { margin:0px }
    .panel:after { 
       content: attr(data-text);
       height:100px; 
       overflow:scroll; /* <- looks like this is the evil css */
       line-height:2em;
       display:block;
 }
</style>
<div class="panel">i see your lips moving but all i understand is bla bla bla </div>
<div class="panel" data-text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non 
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."> yes
</div>
```

can someone confirm this, if you click on the scrollbar that your browser crashes with a mousehandler error?

**EDIT**
just to be exact.. 
*thats the error message in crashreporter log with Safari 5.0.6*
WebCore::RenderLayer::scrollTo(int, int) + 714
WebCore::RenderLayer::setScrollOffset(WebCore::IntPoint const&) + 33
WebCore::ScrollableArea::setScrollOffsetFromAnimation(WebCore::IntPoint const&) + 30
WebCore::ScrollAnimator::notityPositionChanged() + 43
WebCore::ScrollAnimator::scroll(WebCore::ScrollbarOrientation, WebCore::ScrollGranularity, float, float) + 140
WebCore::ScrollAnimatorMac::scroll(WebCore::ScrollbarOrientation, WebCore::ScrollGranularity, float, float) + 300
WebCore::ScrollableArea::scroll(WebCore::ScrollDirection, WebCore::ScrollGranularity, float) + 159
WebCore::Scrollbar::autoscrollPressedPart(double) + 123
WebCore::Scrollbar::mouseDown(WebCore::PlatformMouseEvent const&) + 129
WebCore::EventHandler::passMousePressEventToScrollbar(WebCore::MouseEventWithHitTestResults&, WebCore::Scrollbar*) + 58
WebCore::EventHandler::handleMousePressEvent(WebCore::PlatformMouseEvent const&) + 1424
WebCore::EventHandler::mouseDown(NSEvent*) + 385
-[WebHTMLView mouseDown:] + 475
WebCore::EventHandler::passMouseDownEventToWidget(WebCore::Widget*) + 388
WebCore::EventHandler::passWidgetMouseDownEventToWidget(WebCore::RenderWidget*) + 27
WebCore::EventHandler::passSubframeEventToSubframe(WebCore::MouseEventWithHitTestResults&, WebCore::Frame*, WebCore::HitTestResult*) + 720
WebCore::EventHandler::passMousePressEventToSubframe(WebCore::MouseEventWithHitTestResults&, WebCore::Frame*) + 56
WebCore::EventHandler::handleMousePressEvent(WebCore::PlatformMouseEvent const&) + 462
WebCore::EventHandler::mouseDown(NSEvent*) + 385
-[WebHTMLView mouseDown:] + 475
-[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 5381
0x1000 + 259380
0x1000 + 259265
-[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2939
0x1000 + 223168
-[NSApplication run] + 867
NSApplicationMain + 574
0x1000 + 40174

Comment: i know, would do it as soon as possible, but just wanted to know if this issue is safari 5.0.6 specific or allready solved.

Comment: Using Safari 5.1.9, it does not crash, but it does reload the page. After clicking a few more times, it says something like "this page cannot be displayed" but does not crash.

Comment: and even funny, in chrome it ignores the :after statement and pushes the css to the empty `div.panel` instead of hidden not given css for the first div. a hold on, chrome interprets correct! just does not show the empty àttr(data-text) as expected.

Comment: @icktoofay: It seems to force all other tabs to reload too.

Comment: @codelio: Chrome does not do that for me.

Comment: @BoltClock: You're right. I didn't try it with multiple tabs. I also get the expected result with Chrome.

Comment: so if all tabs reload, it is still a not solved bug. would be nice if someone with safari 6 could try out what happens.

Comment: [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7FpEQ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be slightly fixed in Safari 6. The content is able to scroll on 6.0.3 on my Mac, however I cannot interact with the scrollbar using multi-touch. This means if scrollbars are set to auto-hide in System Preferences, then the content cannot scroll at all. Either way, it does not cause Safari 6 to crash.

Unfortunately, Safari 6 is not available for Windows, and the last version that is available on Windows, 5.1.7, *is* affected by this bug on both platforms. It does not completely crash the browser, though — it simply forces all tabs to reload.

Comment: so i fill a bug report with a link to this stackoverflow question

Comment: Yes, I recommend that you don't just link to the question though - include a self-contained explanation and test case to reproduce, *along* with a link to the question.

Comment: allready send, bug description, html code, and link. thank you all for your quick reply and help

Comment: No problem. Could you dupe the bug on [OpenRadar](https://openradar.appspot.com) and include the radar link here for reference?

Comment: wow! funny, i crashed OpenRadar. :) Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 716, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/openradar/1.366960978367264926/main.py", line 87, in post
    number_intvalue=int(number),
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''